# Datatables 1.10 "Check all" via jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I know this might seem primitive, but I've been trying to implement it for a whole day, maybe because I can't fully comprehend how to use the API, I'm using DataTables 1.10.0, I have a table with pagination feature, each row has one checkbox in it, I need to have a "check all button" that would check all the checkboxes in all pages, the problem is that it only checks the checkboxes in the current page, and leaves the other pages unchecked, this is supposed to be easy, but I couldn't figure it out ! the answers I found use "fnGetNodes" which seems to be deprecated and not used by version 1.10

Edit: this is my markup

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="numbers_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" title="Select all" onClick="toggle(this)"/></th>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Tags</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <% _.each(array, function (value) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' name='numbers[]' value='<%=value.id%>'/></td>
                        <td><%= value.number %></td>
                        <td><%= value.company %></td>
                        <td><%= value.tags %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }) %>
                </tbody>
            </table>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="checkall2">SELECT ALL</button>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#numbers_table').dataTable({
        //"bPaginate": false,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ] 
        });

    $("#checkall2").click(function() { // a button with checkall2 as its id
        $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true); // all checkboxes, you can narrow with a better selector
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide more detail, like actual code you used.

Comment: @LaughDonor I added the code ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var table = $('#numbers_table').DataTable();

var cells = table
    .cells( ":checkbox" )
    .nodes();

$( cells ).prop('checked', true);
```

[Source.](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells%28%29.nodes%28%29)

Comment: Agreed, not sure why this answer was selected. Maybe it was correct in some previous version, I don't have time to check. As it stands today, it is not the solution.

Answer (score 10):

This should work for you

```
var table = $('#numbers_table').DataTable();

    $('#checkall').click(function () {
        $(':checkbox', table.rows().nodes()).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
```

Comment: how to apply css on row that i have selected?

Comment: How can be possible that `table.rows()` throws this exception:


`Uncaught TypeError: table.rows is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:7
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)`

Answer (score 2):

if does not work try using api() keyword:

```
$('#YourCheckBoxId').on('click', function () {
    var rows = YourDatatableVariable.api().rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
    $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It really isn't that hard, but without seeing your markup I can only provide a generic example -

```
$('input[value="Check All"]').click(function() { // a button with Check All as its value
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true); // all checkboxes, you can narrow with a better selector
});
```

Comment: I've already implemented similar code, the problem is caused by datatables pagination, the selector applies to elements in the current page viewed in tables, checkboxes in other pages remain unchecked

Comment: You have to add the logic to your pagination logic because the data is not loaded until you click on a pagination link.

Comment: the "pagination logic" isn't mine, datatables is a plugin and they have a mature API, I already found answers to this problem, but apparently it used older versions of API functions, such as "fnGetNodes", I can't seem to find the functions used in these answers in the current API