# DataTables 1.10 Select All checkbox to select all rows, even hidden rows with pagination

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatable, datatables-1.10

I am new to [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) and have a table with a "Select All" checkbox in the table header row and then each row has a checkbox. I can write code to select all of the visible checkboxes when the "Select All" checkbox is checked, but if there are other pages, those are not getting checked.

I have followed several examples, but none of them seem to work, at least I cannot get them to work. One was here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637586/datatables-1-10-check-all-via-jquery) and it seems to be the closest thing to what I am looking for. All of the others are earlier versions of DataTables and have been deprecated. I have attempted to make the StackOverflow example work, but at this point I am just stuck.

My example code can be found on the [DataTables Live](http://live.datatables.net/riwewuqu/1) site. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There are a couple mistakes in the jQuery example I posted, so I have simplified it here: [DataTables Live Updated Example](http://live.datatables.net/riwewuqu/5/edit). All I want to do at the moment is get all checkboxes on every Page, to be checked when you check the "Select All" checkbox. Until I can get past that, I can't add up the total due.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Using 'payTable.cells()' will return all data rows and not just the visible ones, and I was not able to change 'checked' property, any way.
I solved this by using jquery to change DOM objects:

```
var items = $('[id="cb"]');
items.prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = $('table').DataTable();
var checkedBoxes = table.column(columnIndex).nodes().toJQuery();
```

**you will get all checkboxes under tbody as a JQuery Object**