# how to select all checkbox in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to select all my checkbox

I have an input in header of datatables like this

```
  <th style="width: 25%" ><input type="checkbox" name="checkall" class="select-checkall" id="checkall" value=""></th>
```

i use it like this to checked it but only work in the page that iam

```
   $("#checkall").click(function(){
            $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);                       
     });
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/juxHn/46/

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23675009/4161269

Comment: i try this but not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637586/datatables-1-10-check-all-via-jquery/23675009#23675009   check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/juxHn/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery will not be able to find checkboxes in other pages than the current one because DataTables somehow hides them (maybe removes them from DOM?)

Please refer to DataTables [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) to access your table [cells](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29.nodes%28%29) irrespective of which ones are currently shown or not / of which page you are on.

In your case, you could do:

```js
// Use "DataTable" with upper "D"
oTableStaticFlow = $('#flow-table').DataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        'bSortable': false,
        'aTargets': [0]
    }],
});

$("#flowcheckall").click(function () {
    var cells = oTableStaticFlow.column(0).nodes(), // Cells from 1st column
        state = this.checked;

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i += 1) {
        cells[i].querySelector("input[type='checkbox']").checked = state;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/juxHn/47/

Comment: I found one issue in the above fiddle.

Comment: @vimalkumar Feel free to comment your finding and/or provide your own solution / fixed fiddle.

Comment: Hooray! Well done saved me a lot of head scratching!